# How to make a widget appear smoothly while keeping the anchor

Tags: java, javafx

I want to show a Pane whenever I click a button. The hard side is that I whant the pane to come out smootly for exemple by using a `ScaleTransition` from `width=0` to `width=100` but I whant my pane to be sticked to the side of the frame like you would normaly do with a widget inside an `anchorPane`.

I've tried to apply simutaniusly both a `TranslateTranstion` and a `ScaleTransition`. So the pane seems to expend to his right side. But one these transitions are done, the pane keeps its width and is not resized when the window is.

Comment: Would using `TranslateTransition` and [a clip](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#clipProperty) on the parent work for you? Just keep the child out of the clipped area, then translate it into the clipped area when you want to show it.

Comment: Yeah it worked all fine thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Slaw has answered my question in the comment section so I post his answer.

> Would using TranslateTransition and a clip on the parent work for you? Just keep the child out of the clipped area, then translate it into the clipped area when you want to show it